# Why does my Teams bot work in one to one chat but not in Groups?

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I've been creating a Teams bot using this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-sdk-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=vs
I wanted to create a bot that is capable of working in a team scope. My bot is actually up and running but I can only use it in an one-to-one chat.

If I add it to a team channel via the App Studio I get a message that 'Something went wrong.'.

If I package my manifest and install it to Teams, it will show up the icon on the left side menu. I can enter the channel but if I send a message it tells me there is an 'Error while sending'.

How can I trace down to the orign of the errorsor get some more error details?

Further links I found:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-general-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-bot-configuration?view=azure-bot-service-4.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: Could you please confirm if you have added "team" and "groupchat" scope for your Bot?

Comment: Yes I actually checked all three: Personal, Team and Group Chat.

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot of the error message you see while you install the app in Teams scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using the Teams web app with the chrome debugger I found out, the message request returned with unauthorized code.

The error was that I had a client id in the manifest (created by app studio), from a different installation. This is not valid for the current installation. So I created a new app id and changed it within the project and the manifest. After a redeploy it worked as intended.